# weight painting issue 2.81

Tags: weight-painting

I'm having an issue where when weight painting its crashing every minute of weighting. I'm trying to get used to blender (moving from Maya 2019 to blender) this model was made entirely in blender including its rig.

Computer specs:

i9 9900k (running in turbo 4.6)
32gb DDR4 ram 3200
GTX 1070 TI
1tb storage SSD (used to keep model work on)

Model:

humanoid 
67 bones
44954 tris

Comment: Windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: On windows 10 I'm trying to find a crash log but theres no crash log its an empty folder

Comment: Start Blender with “blender.exe --debug-all” to get debug info

Comment: sorry Im little confused how to do this. Its the first time with doing that

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/launch/windows.html

Comment: `Depsgraph updated in 0.027176 seconds.
UI_menutype_draw: opening menu "TOPBAR_MT_editor_menus"
UI_menutype_draw: opening menu "TIME_MT_editor_menus"
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FF6D50898E1`

Comment: thats what error I got